# unable to see grunt terminal after entering pig command?

Tags: apache-pig

**unable to open grunt terminal after typing pig in Ubuntu, it got stuck and just blinks ,how to debug this issue, restarted the machine and checked .bashrc files.**

[image: pig command to open pig interface in Ubuntu]

[image: pig files directory]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a file with 'pig' installed in (found this using locate command)

> usr/games/

folder ... this is causing problem when i issue the pig command , 
i removed the file,  `rm -rf /usr/games/pig`
and then issued ***pig command*** in ubuntu terminal it worked fine.**

Comment: Haha, oh my. You should report this on the official Ubuntu bugtracker. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu Also, you can mark your answer as the solution - because it is the solution. Thanks for your contribution. || You can also use `which pig` next time to check what will execute if you type in something.